# Quickest way to write <?php echo ... ?>

Tags: php, keyboard-shortcuts, echo, sublimetext2, php-shorttags

There are many questions on stack exchange on whether or not you should use `<?php echo ?>` or `<?= ?>`.

I have decided to use `<?php echo ?>`, but am wondering if there is a good way to create a shortcut to save time writing this.

Currently I use a default setup of Sublime Text 2, with no plugins or anything installed, I'm not a "super user". But I do know that if I type php then press tab it outputs: `<?php ?>`.

Is there a way to get an echo inside this, and is it a good idea to do this? Has anyone done this already?

PS I should add, I don't always want the echo to appear, as I won't always be needing to echo something.

Comment: I guess you bind a macro to output `<?php echo ?>`

Comment: The `<?=` shortcut was deprecated for a while, but has now been brought back; it is no longer considered a bad thing. You should still use the long form `<?php` for any PHP code that isn't a simple echo though.

Comment: "There are many questions on stack exchange on whether or not you should use `<?php echo ?>` or `<?= ?>`." - those questions seem fundamentally dumb to me seeing as it's a bikeshed argument for the most part.

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind a snippet to a keystroke.

```
<snippet>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[<?php echo ${1:What to echo}; ?>]]>
    </content>
    <description>Basic echo</description>
</snippet>
```

Save the above as echo.sublime-snippet in your Packages/User folder then edit **Default (*OS of your choice here*).sublime-keymap** and add

`{ "keys": ["command+e"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"name": "Packages/User/echo.sublime-snippet" } }`

Swap out command-e for any key combination you want to use.
Now, when you hit command & e Sublime will add in
    `<?php echo ;?>` for you and put the insertion cursor right before the ; for you - you can then start to type in what ever needs echoed.

You can also replace `${1:What to echo}` with `$TM_SELECTED_TEXT` and Sublime will wrap the text you've selected with `<?php echo` & `;?>` when you highlight text and hit command & e.

Answer (score 5):

Just re-decide and use shorthand syntax:

```
 <?= ?>
```

it is not only quick in typing but also takes less space

A macro on `<?php` will spoil you every time you need a control structure - `foreach` and such

Answer (score 1):

`php`, TAB, `e`,  TAB and then write the text you want t echo.

#### Note

In order for the auto-completion to work, the document syntax must be PHP. If that's not the case, do `CTRL`+`Shift`+ `P` to open the command pallete, type PHP and choose `Set Syntax: PHP`

Comment: @AnwarHossain Is the current document syntax set to PHP? If not, do `CTRL`+`Shift`+ `P` to open the command pallete, type PHP and choose `Set Syntax: PHP`

Answer (score 0):

You can view the available snippets under Tools > Snippets.  I believe there is a built in snippet for echo which would be simply `echo` and then tab to produce `<?php echo ?>`

To create new snippets go to Tools > New Snippet

[Snippets in the SublimeText2 Docs](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html

Have a look at the existing PHP completion file and you should be able to insert a new one along the lines of:

```
{ "trigger": "?pe", "contents": "<?php  echo ?>" }
```

then you would do `?pe<tab>` - but note I'm not a sublime text 2 user =P